# What's the correlation between treewidth and instance hardness for random 3-SAT?

Tags: graph-algorithms, sat, treewidth, random-k-sat, hard-instances

This recent paper from FOCS2013, [Strong Backdoors to Bounded Treewidth SAT](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.6233) by Gaspers and Szeider talks about the link between the [treewidth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth) of the SAT clause graph and instance hardness.

> For random 3-SAT, i.e. 3-SAT instances chosen at random, what is the correlation between treewidth of the clause graph and instance hardness?

"Instance hardness" can be taken as "hard for a typical SAT solver", i.e. running time.

I am looking for either theoretical or empirical style answers or references. To my knowledge, there do not seem to be empirical studies on this. I am aware there are somewhat different ways to build SAT clause graphs, but this question is not focused on the distinction.

Maybe a natural closely related question is how treewidth of the clause graph relates to the 3-SAT phase transition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not really an answer but the closest references I am aware of. There are results available for branch-width. Also, there is at least one empirical study of treewidth of industrial instances.

- [Discovering treewidth](http://igitur-archive.library.uu.nl/math/2007-0725-201706/2005-018.pdf%E2%80%8E), H. Bodlaender, 2005. Gives algorithms to compute bounds on treewidth.
- [Treewidth in Industrial SAT Benchmarks](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/145390/MSR-TR-2011-22.pdf), R. Mateescu, 2011. Uses variations of above algorithms to estimate treewidth of SAT2009 competition benchmarks.
- [Algorithms and complexity results for #SAT and Bayesian inference](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fbacchus/publications/BDPFOCS2004.pdf), F. Bacchus S. Dalmao, T. Pitassi, 2003. Relates branch-width to complexity of #SAT, 2003.
- [Satisfiability, branch-width and tseitin tautologies](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~razborov/files/automat_pos.pdf%E2%80%8E), Alekhnovich, Razborov, 2002.

Answer (score 7):

In general one would not expect *random* instances of SAT to have bounded treewidth, even if they are easy. Here is an example:

A random k-SAT instance on $n$ variables where each variable occurs in $3$ clauses will be an expander graph, and therefore have treewidth $\theta(n)$ with high probability. This holds in the model where we fix an n and an m (with 3n = km), and pick uniformly at random a formula with n variables and m clauses such that all variables are in exactly 3 clauses. It also holds in the [Erdős–Rényi model](http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0461) with probability set so that variables have average degree $3$.

On the other hand this density is well below the k-SAT phase transition; by the [Lovasz Local Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_local_lemma) *all* $d$-regular $k$-SAT instances are satisfiable for $4 \cdot \frac{1}{2^k} \cdot dk \leq 1$, i.e when $d \leq \frac{2^k}{4k}$

For the other part of your question I'd expect (but I haven't tested this so I don't really know) that SAT solvers should be able to exploit at least some of the symmetries that occur because of all the balanced separators in a bounded treewidth graph: In a k-SAT instance of treewidth $t$ there is a set of variables of size $t$ so that after you branch on these variables the formula breaks up into connected components with less than $n/2$ variables in each.

Comment: thx for ideas. ofc was not expecting that random instances would have bounded treewidth; the opposite is presumably provable without much difficulty. but its a numeric parameter that can be compared/ correlated with hardness similarly to many other parameters studied in SAT empirical transition point research and some relationship or correlation seems to be expected based on existing research.

Comment: @vzn My point is more that in the most common random models the treewidth goes through the roof way before the instances become computationally hard. On the other hand ``real life'' instances probably have much smaller treewidth than random ones and I sort of expect SAT solvers to take (some) advantage of this.